# Можно ли на jsfiddle обойти эту ошибку?

Tags: javascript

Скрипт https://jsfiddle.net/wbuomfsz/1/

```
<div onclick="return add()">показать</div>
<div id="center">
    пример
</div>

var add = function(){
  console.log('add');
}
```

Ошибка `ReferenceError: add is not defined` я догадываюсь возникает из-за того, что HTML вверху, скрипт подключается внизу и на момент нажатия на кнопку функция `add()` ещё не известна. Если бы это былоа простая страница, то скрипт надо было бы вынести выше кода, а на jsfiddle с этим можно что-то сделать что бы работало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там есть опции когда загружать JS. Например функция должна быть заранее объявлена в head (ну или body)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в настройка jsfiddle:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того, чтобы сработал `inline` обработчик, функция должна быть глобальной и объявлена раньше применения.

Для этого стоит поменять настройку на no wrap in head

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/wbuomfsz/3/

Comment: .....too slow :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, долго картинки рисовал :)